# Collection having a count but unable to access items

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to automate some things MS PowerPoint through AppleScript. I'd like to fetch the (shape) selection of the active window. Reading the dictionary, my guess was:

```
tell application "Microsoft PowerPoint"
    set sel to shape range of selection of active window

    count of sel's shapes -- returns 2 for specific case
    -- class of sel's shapes -- throws a compilation error "object you are trying to access does not exist"
    set i to item 1 of sel's shapes -- i not set but this line does not throw an error
    i -- error: the variable i is not defined
end tell
```

with comments indicating what happens when a specific line is run. Interestingly, `sel's shapes` does have a count, but I can't fetch any item from it. My first instinct was that `sel's shapes` must be of some other datatype, but `class sel's shapes` also throws an error, complaining that `sel's shapes` does not exist.

Q: what's going on here? How can `count of` be defined (and work!) whilst `item 1 of` and `class of` are not?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that this is due to the way reference forms are handled in AppleScript (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_reference_forms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH4g-120522).

In this case, the "shape range" does not contain any "items". It only contains "shapes":

```
set s to shape 1 of shape range of selection of active window
```

works just fine:

```
s's left position -- Returns an actual value
```

Lesson learned: take care to use the correct class of item that you are trying to get from a collection.

Comment: Don't forget to check your answer as the accepted answer,  thus boosting your reputation points.